# How can I inspect element in chrome when right click is disabled?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I want to debug a info box that shows when I mouse over a google map marker. But google map disables right click anywhere on the map canvas, so I can't inspect the element for debugging / viewing purposes.

I tried to search for the element by the href content in the elements tab, but it didn't show up on search.

Is there a way to inspect element despite the lack of right click?

Comment: I don't think browsers should let pages block right click. It doesn't achieve anything but frustrating users. We deserve better.

Comment: The question was not asking what everybody thinks about this, sorry

Comment: the problem no elements in console

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Sure, you can open the devtools with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and then click the inspect element button (square with the arrow)

[image]

Comment: That's it! I didn't know about this function. Thanks.

Comment: In case you can't open dev tools with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`, you may open it by clicking on __Developer Tools__ sub-menu from __More Tools__ in Google Chrome menu.

Answer (score 12):

On Mac OS you have to press:
<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: I prefer `CMD`+`SHIFT`+`c`.

Comment: I use `CMD`+`ALT`+`J` :)

Answer (score 9):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Mac) to open the DevTools in Inspect Element mode, or toggle Inspect Element mode if the DevTools are already open.

Answer (score 5):

So use the short cut keys , Press ctrl + shift + I and then Click on Magnifying Option on Left side and Then Hover the mouse cursor and you will be navigate to proper way

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> brings up the developers tools.

Comment: but they can block it to.. the @ehsan88 commant rock =)
or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20661324/1509853) one

Answer (score 3):

Press F12 to Inspect Element and Ctrl+U to View Page Source

Answer (score 2):

**ALTERNATE WAY:**

[image]

Click <kbd>Developer Tools</kbd> to inspect element. You may also use keyboard shortcuts, such as <kbd>CtrlL+Shift+I</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn+F12</kbd>), etc.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS press: `CMD`+`OPTION`+`J` for console