# Disabling inspect element, right click and F12 in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, google-chrome-app

Is there a way to disable inspect element, right click and F12 in google chrome?

Comment: Refer this Link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692006/how-to-uninstall-remove-developer-tools-from-google-chrome

Comment: Do you want a webpage or app to do this (not possible) or a system administrator (or user) to do this?

Comment: on a web page say:www.google.com on right clicking inspect element should not be present

Comment: And why would you need to do this?

Comment: @Dear P.s vinoth are you find the answer,If then kindly guide me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is definitely not possible to do from a web page.

Even if you disable right click and disable the default behaviors for <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+J</kbd>, there is no way to stop a user from opening Dev Tools on a different page and navigating to your page with Dev Tools already open.

Also, you can access Dev Tools by going to <kbd>Menu > Tools > Developer tools</kbd>, which cannot be prevented by any website.

Comment: yeah in-order to prevent the right-click & F12 i used added this code to my DOM window.oncontextmenu = function () {
   return false;
}
document.onkeydown = function (e) { 
 if (window.event.keyCode == 123 ||  e.button==2) 
 return false;
}

Comment: What an absolute statement to make. It is possible, one just have to think hard enough.

Comment: @momomo If you have thought of way that it is possible, please feel free to post an additional answer.

Comment: Yes, and it works. Let's just say the question is how much one is willing to destroy the user experience and how much it is worth to keep them out. I am not going to into great details because it is not in my interest for everyone to start doing that, which will likely become a big enough answer making my life more and more difficult when  I start inspecting other sites in the future. But for my site, I want to keep them out ;)

Comment: @apsillers Think harder. The detection of the dev tools opening is not the question here. That is already possible using various tricks. Once detected there are a number of things one can do.

Comment: @momomo I think there are always ways to open (or keep open) Dev Tools that are undetectable to the page. That appears to be our fundamental disagreement. I have been not been able to think of a way to detect Dev Tools opening by (1) setting dev tools to open a new window instead of a sidecar in-window style, (2) clicking on your page's address bar, and (3) pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I`. (In Chrome, there will always be an address bar.) You can get a `blur` event on the window (only the *first* time, if Dev Tools is not already open, indistinguishable from any other loss of focus).

Comment: @momomo So, I guess if you goal is "completely destroy the page every time it loses focus" you can do that, which would make use Dev Tools hard; I agree. (Not 100% convinced it's impossible, though, since `blur` is a bit finicky.)

Comment: @apsillers Have you tried opening the dev tools on facebook?

Comment: Are you thinking of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools This takes advantage of specific environment states that exist in console code (and may not work anymore?). This doesn't detect or disable dev tools as a whole (notably Inspect, Network, etc)

Comment: No, not thinking of that question. That talks about disabling it in a different way than what I am suggesting. Mine is bullet proof provided of course that you can detect inspector tools, and doesn't disable it per se, but makes it useless and inaccessible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120642/discussion-between-apsillers-and-momomo).

Comment: @User2364902 Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run chromium in a java environment.  This I have seen, then its impossible to open developer tools, and settings etc are not accessable.  But of course it would involve a lot more work and development time.