# is it possible to disable inspect element in browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

For Some websites when I press F12 button to see html elements,Nothing happens.Why?
I test it by ie and google chrome.
Is there any tools to see Element and media of this sites?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reach it from the main menu?
Chromes menu (top right corner)->More tools->Developer tools
You can then use the magnifying glass to inspect a specific element.

It's possible those specific sites swallow your key press, for example in case the focus is in some flash object. See [Disabling inspect element, right click and F12 in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659943/disabling-inspect-element-right-click-and-f12-in-google-chrome) for more info about disabling F12 as JAAulde pointed out.