# How can I inspect element in a webview in chrome when right click is disabled?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web page loaded in a webview element in chrome, but that web page disables the right mouse menu, so I can't launch the debugger.

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried the suggestions the following to no avail :

[How can I inspect element in chrome when right click is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604795/how-can-i-inspect-element-in-chrome-when-right-click-is-disabled)

Using Version 37.0.2062.20 beta (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: So you say, that you can't open DevTools with shortcut? Try FireFox and F12

Comment: F12 should work in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9+

Comment: f12 doesn't work - it does normally, but not for a page in a webview element, only for the app itself.

Comment: What's even more of a problem is that, even when the webview 'guest' page doesn't disable the right-mouse-menu, so I *can* 'inspect element' in it, I *can't* do that when the host web page is stopped on a breakpoint.
Due to the asynchronous relationship between host and guest, it is quite a hinderance to not be able to control debuggers independently.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hit **F12** on keyboard
2. Chose *magnify icon* from *development bar*
3. Inspect Elements on webpage

Comment: f12 doesn't work - not sure why. I try to 'focus' the page in the webview, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The URL 'chrome://inspect' in chrome/chromium will open a page of 'devtools'. The 'app' item on the menu will list all running apps (and other menu items for other inspectable 'entities' like web pages/apps), and you can launch the debugger that way and get the same tools one would expect from the f12 or 'inspect element' on the right-mouse-button menu.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to inspect the page whether the right click is enabled or disabled. This is only for the windows system.

==> When right-click is enabled

1. **Right-click** on the web page & you will find the INSPECT option at the end of the list.
2. Press **F12** & direct inspect window will be opened.
3. Press **ctrl + shift + I** & inspect window will be opened.

==> When right-click is disabled.

1. Press **F12** & direct inspect window will be opened.
2. Press **ctrl + shift + I** & inspect window will be opened.
3. Press **ctrl + shift + J** & inspect window will be opened.